# Increasing induced functions.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, relations

I am studying partial ordered sets. I have a problem with the following example:

$ \text{Let X and Y be sets and } f \in Y^X. \text{The induced functions } f:P(X) \to P(Y)$ and $f^{-1}:P(Y)\to P(X) \text{ are increasing}$.

$P(X) \text{ and } P(Y)$ are power sets of X and Y.

I tried to find a counterexample:
$P(X)=\text{{{a},{b},{c},{a,b},{a,c},{b,c},{a,b,c}} and Y={{d},{e},{d,e}}}$. If I assign {a} to {d,e} and {a,b,c} to {d} then I have {a}$\subseteq${a,b,c} and {d,e}$\nsubseteq${d}. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First observation: the induced function $\wp X\to\wp Y$ will send singletons to singletons, so $\{a\}$ will not be send to $\{d,e\}$. Btw, you forgot the empty sets as elements of powersets.

Comment: I will check again on how to operate with functions using power sets.